# What can i do to use httpclient method in android studio.

Tags: android-studio, httpclient

I am using HttpClient and defaultHttpClient Methods in getInternetData function on android studi. but these methods are no longer part of the SDK 23. how can i overcome this problem.i have used dependencies in build.gradle too , but still error remains here. Kindly tell me are there any other methods to call.?

public class GetMethodEx {

```
public String getInternetData() throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    }finally{
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `HttpClient` is deprecated try using Volley library instead..!!

Comment: yeah . thank you. :)